# How do I prevent Chrome (Canary, v74) from hijacking media keys?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard, itunes

Chrome Canary (74.0.3703.0) has started supporting media controls (I believe Chrome has added and removed this support many times over its lifetime, but this seems to be another [recent addition](https://zdnet.com/article/chrome-73-to-officially-support-the-multimedia-keys-on-your-keyboard/)).

On my MacBook Pro (macOS Mojave 10.14.2 (18C54)), this has the unfortunate effect of no longer allowing the medias key to operate iTunes, even when it is open and/or the focused application.

Does anyone know of a way to turn off this feature in Chrome? I have disabled the flag in `chrome://flags` ([chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls](http://chrome://flags/#enable-modern-media-controls)) and restarted the browser with no success.

[image: screenshot of chrome flags with media controls disabled]

Comment: If you have installed the Google Play Music extension, try to disable or remove it.

Comment: @harrymc, yep, thanks, saw that in another answer as well. I didn't have it installed, but I also removed the YouTube 'app' just in case.

Comment: Did this fix anything?

Comment: @harrymc oops, forgot to mention that part: no, unfortunately uninstalling the app didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable this flag:

```
Hardware Media Key Handling
Enables using media keys to control the active media session. This requires MediaSessionService to be enabled too – Mac, Windows, Chrome OS

#hardware-media-key-handling
```

Comment: To get to the page to disable flags, type `chrome://flags` in the address bar.

Comment: You can also directly type `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` into the address bar.